# Add item to property with an array value in specialized component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have the following component in React

```
const SpecializedTextField= props => {
    return (
        <TextField
            {...props}
            validate={[isNumber, isPositiveNumber]}
        />

    );
};
```

And I want to add another validation to the validate prop:

`<SpecializedTextField validate={[isRequired]} />`

That would add the validation to the TextField so it would result in `validate={[isRequired, isNumber, isPositiveNumber]}`

Of course i could just retrieve both arrays and merge them. But is there a clean way (some sort of syntactic sugar) to append the two properties together in es6/react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Of course i could just retrieve both arrays and merge them.

That's pretty much what you need to do, but it's pretty concise with spread notation:

```
const SpecializedTextField= props => {
    const {validate = [], ...other} = props;
    return (
        <TextField
            {...other}
            validate={[isNumber, isPositiveNumber, ...validate]}
        />

    );
};
```

Of course, that assumes that either you won't get `isNumber` or `isPositive` in the `validate` prop, or that having duplicates isn't a problem. It also creates and spreads a blank array if there's no `validate` prop given.

If those assumptions are invalid and/or creating and spreading the blank array bothers you (it would me, micro-opt or not), you'll need to build a unique set, which you could do yourself or via `Set`. Perhaps:

```
const specializedTextFieldValidations = [isNumber, isPositiveNumber];
const SpecializedTextField = props => {
    let {validate = specializedTextFieldValidations, ...other} = props;
    if (validate !== specializedTextFieldValidations) {
        validate = [...new Set([...specializedTextFieldValidations, ...validate]).values()];
    }
    return (
        <TextField {...other} validate={validate} />
    );
};
```

*(It's too bad the `Set` constructor only accepts a* single *`Iterable` rather than a variable number of them...)*

Speaking of micro-optimization, it would appear that [spread is currently  much slower than `concat`](https://jsperf.com/concat-vs-spread-2), so

```
validate = [...new Set([...specializedTextFieldValidations, ...validate]).values()];
```

may be better written as

```
validate = [...new Set(specializedTextFieldValidations.concat(validate)).values()];
```

Comment: Thanks :) I wasn't aware of spread notation in javascript, I thought it was a feature of React.

Comment: @TimoWillemsen: :-) Spread and rest for arrays and other iterables (what I'm using above) were added to JavaScript in ES2015. Doing them for object properties is currently a [Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) and so won't make ES2017 but probably will make ES2018. The transpilers typically used with React tend to be early adopters, though, which is probably why you thought of them as a React thing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @T.J. Crowder's answer, you don't need to destructure props to extract `validate` and `other`. `validate` prop has the same name and will be overriden due to attribute order in jsx:

```
const SpecializedTextField= props => {
    return (
        <TextField
            {...props}
            validate={[...props.validate, isNumber, isPositiveNumber]}
        />
    );
};

SpecializedTextField.defaultProps = {
    validate: [],
};
```